# How to populate a DataSet (DSet2) based on another DataSet (DSet1)?

Tags: reporting-services, dataset, business-intelligence

Inside the MS BI Studio (2005) for the Reporting Services, how to populate a DataSet (DSet2) based on another DataSet (DSet1) ?

DSet1 carries the result of a specific DB query.

Please kindly advise. Thank you.

Comment: Please can you include a few more details about what you are trying to achieve, such as samples of the output from the first Dataset and what you want to populate the second Dataset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible in general to reference one dataset from another. What are you trying to achieve?